# how to save a path in database with backslashes?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i'm developing a java application using jdbc,mySQL,Query browser.
I want to save an image path in my db. after i save it, it shows, "C:UsersabcDesktop1.png". But I want the path as, "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\1.png"
how to do this?

Comment: Please provide the code showing your path string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code to be portable under another linux system one day, you should use `/` as File separator so save as `C:/Users/abc/Desktop/1.png`.

Java would retrieve the file anyway at the correct path

Comment: i am using windows. when i get a S.out.print it shows correctly. But when save it in db it doesn't. Java doesn't recognize that path.

Comment: what do you mean ? you save as string in the db right ? and when you do new File(dbField), it throws exception or something ?

Answer (score 0):

`"C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\1.png"

You should write it like this.

A \ is used Escape Sequences like \n \r etc.

Comment: I am not writing it. I get it from JFileChooser. yeah. it gets the path with '\\' but cannot save in DB like that.